# Postgresql Concatenating only non null strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

Imagine you have some data in a table similar to the following ...

```
line1               line2               line3       city        zipcode
1 Any Road          NULL                NULL        Big Apple   12345
The White House     Pennsylvania Avenue NULL        Washington  20500
10 Downing Street   NULL                NULL        London      SW1A 2AA
```

How can I return values for the fields that are not null. Taking 'The White House' as an example I would like to return values for all fields except **line3** (as that has a null value) ...

```
The White House, Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, 20500
```

as opposed to ...

```
The White House, Pennsylvania Avenue, **,** Washington, 20500
```

I am trying to convert an ACE/JET/MS Access query into its Postgresql equivalent. In Access I use an IIF similar to ...

```
Select
    IIF(line1 <> '', ', ' + line1, '')
    + IIF(line2 <> '', ', ' + line2, '')
    + IIF(line3 <> '', ', ' + line3, '')
    + IIF(city <> '', ', ' + city, '')
    + IIF(zipcode <> '', ', ' + zipcode, '') as CustDetails
From addresses
```

This would give me exactly what I need. However, Postgres does not appear to have an IIF conditional. I think I need to use 'CASE WHEN THEN' but I am struggling to get my head around nesting things. For example ....

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
     WHEN line1 <> '' THEN line1  || ', '
     WHEN line2 <> '' THEN line2  || ', '
     WHEN line3 <> '' THEN line3  || ', '
     WHEN line4 <> '' THEN line4
 END AS CustDetails
FROM addresses
```

just returns ...

```
custDetails
The White House,
```

How can I nest a Case statement to only show non null values in my results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `concat_ws()` (concat "with separator") it will deal correctly with null values:

```
SELECT concat_ws(',', line1, line2, line3, line4, city, zipcode) as cust_details
FROM addresses;
```

The separator will not be added if any of the elements is null.

If you need it to ignore empty strings, use nullif:

```
SELECT concat_ws(',', line1, nullif(line2,''), nullif(line3,''), nullif(line4,''), city, zipcode) as cust_details
FROM addresses;
```

Comment: It ignores null arguments, but not empty strings (PG12).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
concat_ws(',', line1, line2, line3, city, zipcode)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I appreciate your time and help. a_horse_with_no_name pipped you to the post with the same answer so I accepted that answer, but +1'd yours.

Comment: @Johnny . . . You can accept whatever answer you like.  And, a_horse_with_no_name certainly has a worthy answer.  For the record, though, this answer appeared 12 seconds earlier.  You can hold the mouse by the date (it now says "yesterday") and it will show the exact time.

Comment: 'You can hold the mouse by the date (it now says "yesterday") and it will show the exact time.' I really didn't know you could do that. For me your answer was listed below 'a_horse' and therefore I thought you had been 'pipped'. Thank you for taking the time to point that out to me and for doing it so politely.

Comment: A a side point. I noticed that if the field 'line1' was null, the cancat_ws function fails. It also appears to be the case if there are 2 nulls together, ie, line2 and line3 = null.

Comment: @Johnny . . . I learned that trick years ago from Aaron Bertrand.  In that case, he had beat me to the answer ;)